# Cookie is removed after gmail login

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-socialite

I'm implementing an online reservation system using Laravel Framework version 5.6 and `Laravel Socialite` to implement gmail login.

I have a method that checks if user is logged in before reservation, or it puts `reserveData` and `redirectUrl` specified by an `uniqid` in redis and cookie to fetch it after logging in:

```
public function checkAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    $reserveData = json_decode($request->input('reserveData'), true);
    Session::put('reserveData', $reserveData);

    if (!Auth::check()) {
        $reserveID = uniqid();
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('reserveID'));
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('reserveID', $reserveID, 1440));

        $stepData = [
            'redirectUrl' => route('reserve', ['productId' => $reserveData['productId']]),
            'reserveData' => $reserveData
        ];

        Redis::set($reserveID, serialize($stepData));

        return redirect()->route('redirectToGmail');
    }

    return redirect()->route('reserve', ['productId' => $reserveData['productId']]);
}
```

**redirectToGmail**:

```
public function redirectToGmail()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}
```

The problem is, the `uniqid` doesn't exist in cookie after returning back from gmail **only for the first time that user tries to login**:

```
public function login()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
    dd(Cookie::get());
}
```

Here it is my output of `dd(Cookie::get());` after returning back from gmail:

```
array:4 [▼
    "XSRF-TOKEN" => "DxiHpLSqB8juOkdLSptORyXs2XGggwWuY4tKJDkz"
    "project_session" => "Gy7p3nhUNGF9D34FmWYxyvewb6juiDNSVLXWTDvS"
    "__cfduid" => null
]
```

Comment: I found the issue! Cookie Queuing for API requests is not enabled by default. You can add the following in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

`\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,`

In  `protected $middleware = []`, or as a middleware in `api.php`

Comment: @Garrett I have already added it to `$middleware` array of `app/Http/Kernel.php` and also passed it as middleware option to the `route`. But it still doesn't work for the first time that I call the `gmail` api.

Comment: Could you share your output of dd(Cookie::get()) ?

Comment: @Garrett I edited the question and added the output of `dd(Cookie::get())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel by default sets the `domain` parameter of `Cookie::make()` method to current host address, that it contains `www.` sub domain in it. As you can see it by calling **getHost()** method:

```
request()->getHost(); // returns e.g. www.yourdomain.com
```

The return url that I had already registered in gmail service was `mydomain.com/return/url`. I had set the cookie without passing any domain to it, so the default host address was set that it differences with the registered domain in gmail.

I removed the previous domain (mydomain.com/return/url) from gmail and registered it with `www.` sub domain (www.mydomain.com/return/url). Also I passed the `path` and `domain` arguments to **Cookie::make()** method and it works like a charm ;) **:**

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('reserveID', '/', $request->getHost()));
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('reserveID', $reserveID, 1440, '/', $request->getHost()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The url of the site before and after login Gmail is the same?
If the url changed, the cookie will be reset.